# SailsJS Redis connection string on Azure

Tags: javascript, azure, sails.js

I'm trying to connect Azure Cache for Redis in my SailJS project but get an error called "A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load!" Locally I use this string which works > redis_url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'

Azure supplies a Primary Key, let us call it xyz and a Primary Connection string imageAware.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=xyz,ssl=True,abortConnect=False

I have tried the following string in my config file but that is when I get the above error. redis_url: 'redis://:xyz@imageAware.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0'

Which is the correct format for the Azure Cache for Redis connection string?

Comment: Did you override the redis_url value in `config/production.js`?

Comment: Yes. From 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' to 'redis://:xyz@imageAware.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0'

Comment: Can I get a code snippet of how you are setting it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding the following to my production.js file.

```
    session: {
        adapter: '@sailshq/connect-redis',
        url: 'redis://:xyz=@imageAware.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            secure: false
        }
    },
```